# Checked Checkbox should be not uncheckable

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have some difficulty settings in a game. Because only one option should be active at once i did e.g. for option 'Easy'

```
//Uncheck all other difficulty options
if(ui->actionMedium->isChecked())
{
    ui->actionMedium->setChecked(false);
}

if(ui->actionHard->isChecked())
{
    ui->actionHard->setChecked(false);
}
```

Now the problem is that if i click on an already checked checkbox the checkbox will uncheck. Ok, thats the normal behaviour of a checkbox, so i added

```
//check if its alreay checked
if(ui->actionEasy->isChecked())
{
    ui->actionEasy->setChecked(true);
}
```

but this doent work and i dont understand why.

As alternativ i could group radiobuttons, but i would like to unterstand why my code doent work.

Comment: To select one of several mutually exclusive options you should use radio buttons, not checkboxes. Using checkboxes incorrectly by adding custom behavior is a bad idea.

Comment: What is last code snippet supposed to do? If easy is checked set easy checked? It doesn't make much sense.

Comment: you should add settings changes for all three in every function. So if  one is set checked, the other are set unchecked in the same `if`. But I also agree with @bames53

Comment: I thought that if i do this a checkbox is uncheckable if its already checked. Unfortunately i was wrong. It seems that Qt will check if the checkbox is checked after the code will be executed and so the code as you said is useless ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you uncheck the checkbox actionEasy `ui->actionEasy->isChecked() == false` and so your code doesn't check this checkbox.

Comment: Thanks. So Qt switches the check state before the code is executed.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look [here](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/widgets-groupbox.html) it will teach you how to group items and make just one checkable at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Disable checkbox once it is checked.